# DevExpress Winform controls Radiobutton group

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am working on a winform  application where I need to present a radiobutton group for allowing users to specify options among mutually exclusive ones. The DevExpress control radiobutton  group looks like not flexible enough. For example , it does not allow arranging the individual radios in a different layout , nor it allows me to attach other controls ( like a text box ) to one of the radio that will get enabled when the radio button is selected ( and similar customizations.. ) Am I missing something or is it a case where I need to write my own user control( I can assemble my own control from the good old Winform controls quickly to get this , but I want to make sure there's nothing already like this from DevExpress ) ?

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to position radio buttons the way you need. This can be done using separate CheckEdits.  To make them work as radioButtons belonging to the same RadioGroup, set the editors'

Properties.RadioGroupIndex to the same value
Properties.CheckStyle to Radio

Hope, this helps.

Comment: glory for you and your family